# Create .app / .dmg with Esky

Tags: macos, python-3.x, cx-freeze, esky

I'm developing a GUI app in Python. I use `cx_Freeze` to turn my app into `.app/` / `.dmg` files for OS X users. So, for instance I can use `python setup.py bdist_dmg` to make cx_Freeze create a `.dmg` file that my users can use to install my app.

I now want my app to update itself automatically. [Esky](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky) seems to be a promising framework for doing this. I can do `python setup.py bdist_esky` to create a version of my app that updates itself. It produces the following directory structure:

- `myapp`
- `myapp-0.1/`

  - `myapp`
  - ...
- ...

The top-level `myapp` is Esky's bootstrapping executable. It looks in the current directory, finds `myapp-0.1/` as the latest version and then launches `myapp-0.1/myapp`.

How do I package this into a `.dmg` file which I can ship to my users? After my modifications to `setup.py` to get `bdist_esky` to work, `bdist_dmg` no longer works. The impression I get is that Esky is simply not meant to be used with `bdist_dmg`. Its documentation doesn't mention `DMG` files at all and I also couldn't find anything on Google.

As a first step, I tried to manually turn the files generated by Esky into an OS X `.app/` bundle:

- `myapp.app/`

  - `Contents/`

    - `Info.plist`
    - `MacOS/`

      - `myapp`
      - `myapp-0.1/`

        - `myapp`
        - ...
      - ...

`Info.plist` contains the minimum amount of necessary information to get OS X to run `myapp`. When I try to run `myapp.app` however, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 318, in bootstrap
  File "<string>", line 442, in get_best_version
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/michael/Temp/myapp.app/appdata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 689, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 335, in bootstrap
RuntimeError: no usable frozen versions were found
```

Looking at Esky's source code, it appears to have some special handling for OS X bundles in its `appdir_from_executable(...)` function. To make Esky happy, I tried to rearrange my files so `appdata/` actually exists:

- `myapp.app/`

  - `appdata/`

    - `myapp-0.1/`

      - `myapp`
      - ...
  - `Contents/`

    - `Info.plist`
    - `MacOS/`

      - `myapp`
      - ...

Unfortunately, this results in another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 689, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 336, in bootstrap
  File "<string>", line 363, in chainload
  File "<string>", line 425, in _chainload
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'exc_value' referenced before assignment
```

Is this really that difficult? Am I the only one who wants to use Esky *and* ship files to users in the (standard) `.dmg` format? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael, I saw your comment in [the github issue](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/issues/74#issuecomment-72247701) as well. Let me answer it here.

I had the same requirement and resolved in a similar way but I think I didn't use cx_Freeze. Another difference could be that I used Python 2.7.x. The best way to help you is to show you a few relevant files which worked well for me for creating .app and .dmg.

1) The main setup file of the python project:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13110611/temp/package_esky/setup_esky.py

2) The utility script I used to prepare some data files etc
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13110611/temp/package_esky/prepare_setup.py

3) The main shell script I used to create app and DMG. That is, this script will call everything else, and it's the only script I used from command line directly.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13110611/temp/package_esky/package.sh

4) The dmg-setup script which will create DMS from .app file. It's just a simple wrapper script to call [create-dmg](https://github.com/andreyvit/create-dmg), an open souce project.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13110611/temp/package_esky/dmg-setup

Please try and let me know in case you have any other questions or issues.

Comment: Thanks so much Jake. I think the main reason why your approach works is that you are using py2app, not cx_Freeze. I read up on it and found the following in Esky's tutorial: `On Mac cxfreeze doesn't output a .app file. If you plan on packaging your executable with a program that requires a .app you are better off using py2app.` I dug a little deeper however and actually did find a way to get Esky to work with cx_Freeze: You need to set its `bootstrap_code` option to `'appdir_from_executable = dirname\nbootstrap()'`. Either way, many thanks!

Comment: Hi @MichaelHerrmann, I know this comment is a little late, but can you link the article to the solution to work with Esky and cx_freeze?

Comment: @elams Esky is unmaintained and I've long since switched to https://build-system.fman.io (of which I am the author).